# In DBT - Setting a custom schema for a seed makes the ref not work

Tags: dbt

We started using the seeds functionality in DBT, we put a single CSV file in the data folder, and configured the seed to use a custom schema named util  --- and it works (i.e. - it creates a table in the correct schema).

yaml looks like this:

```
seeds:
  my_project_name:
    +schema: util
```

However, when we refer to it using ref in our models:

```
{{ref('my_seed')}}
```

it looks for it in our default target schema for the environment (public ), instead of the custom one we defined --- how come?

I should mention that we also used the macro trick mentioned here:
https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-custom-schemas

Update:
Adding the macro code we used (as the file *get_custom_schema.sql*):

```
{% macro generate_schema_name(custom_schema_name, node) -%}
    {{ generate_schema_name_for_env(custom_schema_name, node) }}
{%- endmacro %}
```

Comment: To confirm, have you added the `generate_schema_name` to your project? If so, could you add the macro to the post?

Comment: yep, i used the exact macro as given in the example in the dbt docs, i'll add it

Comment: also, if it helps, I believe i ran dbt locally using 17.0 and our cloud dbt deployment runs 17.2

Comment: After digging a bit in Cloud DBT and the docs, it seems like it's caused by the target name for the job being defined as "default" (which i also believe is the default value for a job?) rather than "prod" --- I have to admit I never quite understood that - and what are we supposed to put there in Cloud DBT... (i.e. - what's the relationship between the "environment" and the "target name" of a job..)

https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/dbt-cloud/using-dbt-cloud/cloud-setting-a-custom-target-name/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the `+` is needed in front of `schema`, based on the [code example here](https://docs.getdbt.com/faqs/seed-custom-schemas/).

Another option would be to define the schema for the specific seed table:

```
seeds:
  my_project_name:
    my_seed:
      schema: util
```

Comment: Sorry, but no - that wasn't the issue. the problem was that the "target name" in DBT cloud must be named as "prod" in order for this to work well.